# Control queue concurrency by tenant in multi-tenancy system

Tags: c#, azure, concurrency, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

I have a multi-tenancy system and need to guarantee FIFO (first-in-first-out) processing of queued messages by tenant, i.e. each tenant would get its own `MaxConcurrentCalls = 1`.

To be done in Azure and technology not fixed.

I know this could be achieved by creating a separate WebJob for each tenant, but that limits scalability.

Are there any other ways to achieve such a behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned Service Bus, I suggest

- Use Service Bus Queues or Topics with Sessions enabled
- Assign session identifiers based on tenant ID

This way you should be able to process messages one-by-one and in-order per tenant, but multiple tenants in parallel.

Comment: +1 Note that with this approach you'd be able to scale out for growing number of tenants. Per tenant there will be only a single consumer (known limitation when processing messages with Sessions).

Comment: This seems to be the right approach, but Microsoft is behind on all feature requests for this on WebJobs and Functions (I see you in the github discussion). Where do you run your code? VM/WorkerRole or do you have it working in WebJobs?

Comment: @BenjaminE. We are running Web Jobs without using Web Job SDK triggers. Just a console app reading sessions itself.